# An Introduction to Functional Analysis: Prerequisites

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

There is a Coursera course starting this January called "An Introduction to Functional Analysis". I am interested in taking this course, but I'm not sure whether or not the material will be beyond me at this point in my math education. By the time I start the course, I will have completed MIT's OCW on Linear Algebra, and be about halfway done with OCW Differential Equations, and be about 2/3 of the way through multivariate calculus, having a start on Vector Calculus. Do you think this will be enough background to start the course? If not, what could I read up on in the meantime (if feasible) to be prepared for the course? Thank you ahead of time.

Introduction to Functional Analysis: https://www.coursera.org/course/functionalanalysis

Comment: I don't feel like this should be posted as an answer, but I think you will be ok with that. I'd just keep studying multivariable calculus in parallel but it is not essential.

Comment: Functional analysis is a story about linear algebra and general topology. You should know some basic linear algebra, including spectral theorem for normal matrices and the Jordan canonical form for general matrices. You should know basic analysis---both integration and differentiation, for example, are basic examples of linear operators on infinite dimensional spaces.